# Unable to zip file using 7 zip from jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I need to zip/compress multiple files from a folder and send it on email using jenkins setup.
So , I have created a job in Jenkins to run `.bat` file of automation framework.
after runnig it generates multiple .html file. I need to send these files on email using jenkins after zipping these files.

I have written batch command for same and if I run that manually by double clicking the bat file then compressed folder is getting created.

But when I run this using jenkins job then error is getting displayed:

```
'7z' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have added 7zip path in environment variable but still getting this error in jenkins.

Command added in jenkins to navigate to .bat folder file:

```
cd ..\output\ZipFolder filename.bat
```

Command added in .bat file:

```
7z a -t7z "destinationpath/filename.7z" "sourcepath\*.html"
```

Comment: Can you update the path environment variable from within the batch script and see if the error still exits?

Comment: Have you restarted the server? The path variable needs to be updated first.

Comment: @AmeyaVS  : Thank you so much for the answer. This worked perfectly for me.